# Is it possible to change interactivity in Carto.js map when called from Carto

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am making a carto map using carto.js and a map/data from my Carto account. I know I can set the interactivity there for clicking on polygons, etc. in the wizard, but am not able to alter that in my carto.js code.

Example:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, vizjson)
                .addTo(map)
                .on('done', function(layer) {
                    layer.setInteraction(true);

                    var subLayerOptions = {
                        sql: "SELECT * FROM final_1",
                        cartocss: "#final_1{polygon-fill: #F84F40; line-color: #000;}",
                        interactivity: "name"
                        }

                    var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

                    sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);

                    sublayers.push(sublayer);

                    alert("this is a map");


                });
```

My `subLayerOptions` `interactivity` line does not seem to have any effect on the data when I include that line. Instead, it just displays a popup that is forever "loading". How can I set the interactivity in the carto.js code instead of on the Carto builder side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the interactivity, you need to add an infowindow to display a pop up. [Here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods/#sublayerinfowindow) you have the documentation. In addition, have a look at [this working example](https://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/3950e1a9b458a9177f9c). Basically, you have to add two things:

- an infowindow template, such as this one:

> ```
> <!-- HTML template for custom infowindow -->
> <script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
>     <div class="infowindow-custom">
>       <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
>        <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
>         <div class="content" style="padding:20px">
>           <h3>Name:</h3> 
>           <p>{{content.data.name}}</p>
>       <div>
>       <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
>     </div>
> </script>
> ```

- and add this method to the visualization object:

> cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(
>         map, layer, ['name'],
>         {
>            infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').html()
>         });