# Add two sublayers at once Carto.js

Tags: carto, carto-js

How can I have two sublayers on at once in carto.js? I'm very much struggling on how to accomplish this. My code is [here](https://bl.ocks.org/moman822/51921129802cc7890754496b9e8235ab), I have gotten so far as to hide and display each sublayer with a checkbox, but cannot get them to appear together.

Relevant code:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, vizjson)
                .addTo(map)
                .on('done', function(layer) {

                    var subLayerOptions = {
                        sql: "SELECT * FROM final_1",
                        cartocss: "#final_1{polygon-fill: #F84F40; line-color: #000;}",
                        //interactivity: "name"
                        }

                    var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

                    sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);

                    sublayers.push(sublayer);

                    //alert("this is a map");


                });

            $('#bhp').on('change', function() {
                if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
                    $('p1').html("something") } else {
                    $('p1').html("else")};
                    });

            var LayerActions = {
                bhp: function(){
                    sublayers[0].setSQL("SELECT * FROM final_1 WHERE mms_num= 2277 ");
                    sublayers[0].setCartoCSS('#final_1{polygon-fill: #e65400; line-color: white; }');
                    return true;    
                },
                noLayer: function() {
                    sublayers[0].setSQL("SELECT * FROM final_1 WHERE 1=0");
                    sublayers[0].setCartoCSS('#final_1{polygon-fill: #e65400; line-color: white; }');
                    return true;  
                },

                bp: function(){
                    sublayers[0].setSQL("SELECT * FROM final_1 WHERE mms_num= 2481");
                    sublayers[0].setCartoCSS('#final_1{polygon-fill: #009400; line-color: white; }');
                    return true;    
                }
            };

            $('#bhp').on('change', function() {
                if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
                    LayerActions['noLayer']()} else {
                    LayerActions[$(this).attr('id')]()}
                });

            $('#bp').on('change', function() {
                if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
                    LayerActions['noLayer']()} else {
                    LayerActions[$(this).attr('id')]()}
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler (and working) way to add sublayers. Check out [this working example](https://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/6a83dbae9d6e984ca938).

- First, it creates a `layers` object, containing the query and styles for each sublayer.
- Then, after creating an "empty layer", it adds a function that triggers when the input/checkbox is activated.
- Finally, it clears the sublayers and adds the sublayers that are activated.

Comment: I have seen that example but found that I could not get the interactivity to work on my sublayers. Any idea on that?

Comment: I have just posted an answer to your other question related to interactivity. So, is this question solved?

Comment: Thanks for looking at both of these. Your answer on the other question worked to set the interactivity for the base layer but not on the sublayers when called using the method suggested by your answer here.

Comment: do you know how I can add interactivity for the sublayers created this way?

Comment: could you share the code [with the corrections (with the other question)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217569/41250)?

Comment: I actually got it to work by moving where I had put the `infoWindow` method to inside the `.done` function. Thanks for your help!